# More than 99 references using natbib in Overleaf LaTeX

Tags: latex, bibtex, biblatex

I'm currently writing my thesis and I've run into a problem where I have more than 99 references. normally i would used biblatex for my references and just the command:

```
\usepackage[maxbibnames=150]{biblatex}
```

to increase my max references limit to 150. I however need to use the mnras bibliography style which is only available in natbib. natbib only allows up to 99 references and theres no clear way of increasing it.

natbib only allows 99 references as it formats numbered items in the bibliography to have two characters width (which the mnras template hides)
i tried changing the digit allowance with

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{mnras}

%%% other thesis gubbins %%%

\begin{thebibliography}{999} %here, making 3 digit numbers acceptable
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{thebibliography}
```

but to no avail.

any help short of having to make my own cite style for biblatex would be appreciated.

Comment: Please make a [mre] which allows us to reproduce your problem

Comment: And why on Earth are you wrapping `\bibliography` in a `thebibliography` environment ????

Comment: Not sure reproducible example is a good idea here, as 100 citations would be needed.

Comment: @tomdavison Where's the problem? That's what collections like `biblatex-examples.bib` are for that are automatically included in all complete latex installation.

Comment: The issue is likely with the clashing with the mnras files though. You're suggesting several thousand lines be added as an example? Not a great idea

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but the mnras .bst file should already handle bibtex. With bibtex there would be no limit in citations. For instance in their main template they recommend this

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% REFERENCES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% The best way to enter references is to use BibTeX:

\bibliographystyle{mnras}
\bibliography{example} % if your bibtex file is called example.bib
```

If you use the MNRAS .bst and .cls files, you shouldn't need to include any bibliography management tools; they have that covered. (So no \usepackage... commands).